# CSS hardware acceleration doesn't work well

Tags: android, css

I used it like this

```
.item{
      -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0px;
transition: 0.4s;
}
```

animation demo : http://jsfiddle.net/q1a4wwar/13/

```js
$(function() {
  $('.item').on('click', function() {
    $(this).addClass('slideLeftItem');
    $('.content').show(0, '', function() {
      $('#back').show();
    }).addClass('slideRightContent');
  });


  $('#back').on('click', function() {

    $('.item').show().removeClass('slideLeftItem');
    $(this).hide();
    $('.content').removeClass('slideRightContent').once('transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd otransitionend MSTransitionEnd',

      function() {
        $(this).hide();
      });
  });
});
```

```css
.content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: -200px;
  top: 0px;
  background: blue;
  transition: 0.4s;
}
.item {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}
.slideRightContent {
  right: 0px;
}
.slideLeftItem {
  left: -200px;
}
#back {
  display: none;
  height: 20px !Important;
  background: grey !Important;
}
.content,
.item {
  width: 100%;
  ;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
}
.phone {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 200px;
  border: 10px solid #000;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="back">
  < back</div>
    <br>
    <div class="phone">
      <div class="item">item</div>
      <div class="content">My content</div>
    </div>
```

but it still lags on my phone (*Galaxy SIII*).

Am I using the css hardware acceleration correctly?

Comment: Why would you be using a 3D transform when in your demo there is no evidence for the need of it? It looks like you need something *much* simpler than this (unless there are other factors for its use which you've not included). Use something like **transform: translate(0, 0);** instead (with vendor prefixes)

Comment: @jbutler483 so it's correct to put transform: translate(0, 0); at the .item?

Comment: Yes, since you are only doing a 2D translation.

Comment: @jbutler483 no changes, still lag.. maybe I shouldn't do addClass. Any faster method?

Comment: I feel that you could remove/rewrite most of the jquery code (and still get the functionality). However, this might be better on the codereview part of the site, but give me a few mins n I might be able to throw something together for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/q6a0y4zv/1/) seems to be a simplified example of what you were achieving (and could still be improved drastically).

It's using the css of:

```
transform: translate(-200px,0);
```

(with [vendor prefixes](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d))

```js
$(".heading").click(function() {
  $(".heading").addClass("toggle").removeClass("toggleBack");
  $(".content").addClass("toggle").removeClass("toggleBack");
  $(".back").addClass("displayMe");
});

$(".back").click(function() {
  $(".wrapper div").removeClass("toggle").addClass("toggleBack");
  $(".back").removeClass("displayMe");
});
```

```css
html,body{margin:0;padding:0;}
.wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 5px solid black;
  background:red;
}
.wrapper div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.back {
  display: none;
}
.toggle {
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-200px, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate(-200px, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate(-200px, 0);
  -o-transform: translate(-200px, 0);
  transform: translate(-200px, 0);
}
.toggleBack {
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate(0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate(0, 0);
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}
.displayMe {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="back">back</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="heading">FirstPage</div>
  <div class="content">NextDiv</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I didn't do this because there will be a slide back, try my demo again.

Comment: good solution but inline block won't work in my case, because I will have multiple item and content

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply [`transform-style: preserve-3d`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-style) and [`position: relative`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) on the parent element to make it work correctly.

> **preserve-3d**
>
> Indicates that the children of the element should be positioned in the
>   3D-space.

then add

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-perspective: 1000;
```

to the child element.

Let us say your parent has the class `parent` the full code would then look like this

```
.parent{
      position: relative; /*do not niss this it is very important since the child has an obsolute position*/
      transform-style: preserve-3d
}
.item{
      transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
      perspective: 1000;
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 0px;
      transition: 0.4s
}
```

Comment: I see but which parent?

Comment: try to apply to my case, transform-style: preserve-3d; make my stuff broken